# PayPal Rest API - List transactions from a billing agreement

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I developed some weeks ago a payment service for my web in django using PayPal subscriptions. At that moment, all I did worked fine, but when I am testing it now to upload to production server, the function to get the history of payments of one specific billing agreement doesn't work.

The function does this:

```
try:
    billing_agreement = paypalrestsdk.BillingAgreement.find(request.POST.get("id"))
    transactions = billing_agreement.search_transactions("2014-01-01", time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
except Exception, e:
    ...
```

So, anyone could help me to get that to work? I have seen some GitHub's codes using this way to get the history of payments and it worked for me some weeks ago, but not today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Avi from PayPal. There were changes in the api recently, and getting the transactions endpoint changed from /transaction to /transactions. We released a new version of the sdk to reflect these changes. Updating the sdk should resolve these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the sdk from version 1.4.0 to 1.4.1. Now, if I print my local variable `transactions` I get an empty DictType `{}`, instead absolutely nothing as before. I've checked in sandbox web that this agreement id has some transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the url 
New url is of type

https://{URL}/v1/payments/billing-agreements/{Agreement-Id}/transactions?start_date=
{yyyy-mm-dd}&end_date={yyyy-mm-dd}

Path params are start_date & end_date

Thanks